# Can IIS 7 request filters be used to deny a route for certain domains?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, requestfiltering

I have a website setup in IIS 7.5 which has bindings to two domains names, for example:

- www.examplesite.com
- www.anothersite.com

Which means someone visiting to either address in their browser would see exactly the same site.

What I want to achieve is to **deny requests** to `/admin` for people visiting `www.examplesite.com/admin` - but for requests to `www.anothersite.com/admin` **to go through**.

However when using the request filtering features in IIS, it only seems possible to apply the filtering to the URL excluding the domain name. Meaning that `/admin` would be denied for both domains.

**Is this possible? If not through IIS 7.5 request filters, then what's the easiest alternative?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an IIS solution you should consider the URL Rewrite extension for IIS.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

I've been using it in our server farm to rewrite website URLs and have found it is very powerful.

Here is a similar example of what you are trying to achieve, in your case you could apply a Regex or Wildcard filter to the Raw URL instead of the Host header:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template

When you say **deny requests**, it depends on what you want the user experience to be. It could be an Abort Request, Custom Response (403), Redirect etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use iis to handle this. Just place a simple redirect in the page that checks for the URL and if they typed examplesite/admin..redirect to a "noaccess" page...